# My <div> is overlapping my drop-down tabs

Tags: html, css

I've been having a hard time on my website with my div tags... every time I hover over the arcade tab or other drop-down menu, it drops behind my div for my movies! I want this to be the opposite where the tabs overlay the divs. Any suggestions?

This is the CSS I've been using:

```
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul {
    background: #efefef; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #D8D8D8  10%, #D0D0D0 90%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #D8D8D8  10%, #D0D0D0 90%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #D8D8D8  10%, #D0D0D0 90%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
}
    nav ul li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

nav ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 10px 40px;
    color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
    font-family:arial;
}
nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0px;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
}
    nav ul ul li a {
        padding: 10px 40px;
        color: #fff;
        font-family:arial; font-weight:900;
    }   
        nav ul ul li a:hover {
            background: #4b545f;
        }
nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

This is my HTML on the page for what it's overlapping:

```
    <div id="text"><h1>Featured!</h1></div>
<div id="boxed">
    <div id="movie">Ghost Shark</br><img src="/movies/posters/Ghost Shark.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the HTML for my nav pane:

```
<center><nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Arcade</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/arcade/action">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/arcade">Arcade</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/puzzle">Puzzle</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/vehicle">Vehicle</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/violence">Violence</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/defense">Defense</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/rpg">RPG</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Watch</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/watch/tv">TV Shows</a></li>
            <li><a href="/watch/movies">Movies</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Extras</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="/updates">Updates</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/support">Support</a></li>
</ul>
</nav></center>
```

The website it is on is http://gameshank.com/movies/horror/

Thanks is advanced!

Comment: That's not the effect shown on your site. Your site pushes the movie div down, it doesn't go under it. Also, please provide the HTML for your nav

Comment: Add `z-index: 9999;` to `nav ul ul`

Comment: Sorry, just fixed it back to what it was and updated the code in my question.

Comment: And @Zeaklous I added the HTML for my tabs for reference!

Comment: @AustinBunker you thanked ninty yet it was answered a minute earlier with the same answer!?

Comment: ^^ This guy didn't check the comments on the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a higher `z-index` to your `nav`

```
nav {
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Why does everyone give absurd z-indexes as examples?

Comment: @Zeaklous for examples sake. Armed with this information the user can then research how it works and decide on the values best suited to the layering system they wish to adopt. Also, for `z-index` 1000 isn't high, as for adverts the industry standard is `1,000,000`+

Comment: But all that is necessary is `1`. And it starts bad practices in new programmers setting random `z-index`es which they lose track of and ultimately makes it harder for them to find problems that may come up in their code